# How to map specific cell contents from multiple workbooks into a single sheet

Tags: python, excel

I have 60 workbooks with multiple sheets in them. I need to map specific cell contents from all workbooks to a master excel file.
For example: I need to map data from Cell B5 of worksheet 1 from all workbooks to Cell I5 and onwards of master workbook.

Similarly, further I need to map Cell B7 from Worksheet 2 to Cell H5 and onwards of the master workbook!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This code works for me, you can use an array for the sheets iterations

```
from xlrd import open_workbook

wb = open_workbook(file_name)
sheet = wb.sheet_by_index(sheet_index)
print(sheet.cell_value(row_index, col_index))
```

I'm using xlrd version 1.2.0